# How to use setState to render individual data returned from API call using map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

How do I use setState to render individual data returned from API call. As the question implies... What I am getting instead is another array of data.

Here's the code:

```
const [likes, setLikes] = useState(0);

  useEffect( async () => {

    const query = await getDevsApi();    //This returns a collection of data I can map.
    const likes = query.map(like => like.upvotes);    //The problem  here is, it returns an array of data... How do I get individual data for each user? and set it at as the current state in the setLikes() below.

    setLikes(likes)

  },[]);
```

I am still wrapping my head around reactjs. Can anyone explain the best approach for me?

[How it looks...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkRAS.png)

UPDATED CODE
ver. 1.

```
const [likes, setLikes] = useState(0);
useEffect(() => {
    //using an anonymous async function inside a useEffect
    ( async () => {
      const query = await getDevsApi();
      setLikes(query.map(like => like.upvotes));
      })
      (); //calling the anonymous function.
},[]);
```

ver. 2.

```
const [likes, setLikes] = useState(0);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    ( async () => {
        const query = await getDevsApi();
        const likes = query.map(like => like.upvotes);
     setLikes(likes);
      })
      (); 
    },[]);
```

However, they both produce the same result.

The idea is to get the number of likes from the API and display them in this section

```
<span className={styles.iconLeft}>
<a href="#" onClick={addLike} ><small>{likes} Likes  <FontAwesomeIcon className={styles.columnIcon} icon={faHeart} /></small> </a>
</span>
```

The {likes} is where the magic happens. The initial state was set to 0... and the useEffect will be used to display the real data gotten from the API. And Yes, I got the data BUT it's not distributed to each user as supposed, rather it's giving me an array and appending it to all the user.
See the screenshot above.
I hope I'm able to communicate clearly though.

I just pushed my project to vercel.
here is a branch of what I am having now... https://naijadev-4g9llmolb-badt0men.vercel.app/

And here is another branch of how I want it... https://naijadev-five.vercel.app

And yes this is my very first attempt working with Jamstack... using the now popular headless CMS (strapi)

Comment: You should never pass an `async function` to `useEffect` read more about it here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: Can u please update your question with how the current response looks like? and what are you expecting it to look like?

Comment: `const likes =  query.map(like => ({name: like.userName, likes: like.upvotes}));` as I am amusing that u also get the user info in your response.

Comment: @vajad57 Thanks for pointing out the issue about using async in useEffect
 And this is what it looks like in the console and on screen. When in fact, I need all the elements in the array to be mapped individually to the cards.

Comment: @Justin How do I get to call/use the upvotes data?

Comment: By showing more code. You need to rewrite your useEffect because it should not be doing async work, and you should show the rest of your function, in [mcve] form, so that folks can see both the code you're using, and get an understanding of your level of proficiency with React so they can give appropriate advice/help.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans could you please review as I have updated the code after a few pointers here.

Comment: Remember the [mcve] aspect: at the very least, show the full component function. A const and useEffect on its own "do nothing", show them in the context of your (minimal, reduced) component function.

Comment: @Badt0men  u can access upvotes data using `{likes.likes}`

Answer (score 0):

The `map()` method **creates a new array** populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array. see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

But this won't be an issue. if you want to render individual data from an array you should use the `map()` method in the `return` block of a functional component where UI is rendered.

```
const [likes, setLikes] = useState([]);

  useEffect( async () => {

    const query = await getDevsApi(); 
    const likes = query.map(like => like.upvotes); 

    setLikes(likes)

  },[]);
return (
...
  <span className={styles.iconLeft}>
    { likes?.map(like => <a href="#" onClick={addLike} ><small>{like} Likes  
      <FontAwesomeIcon className={styles.columnIcon} icon={faHeart} /></small> </a> 
    }
  </span>
)
```

Comment: This question is still not resolved. I probably didn't state it clearly the other time.
Here is the issue. I am using the Nextjs getStaticProps method and after destructing, I am able to access the likes using the map() function. Now, the data are well layed out but I do not know how I can update the counter SINCE the initial State is gotten from the data from the getStaticProps and map() function above and not explicitly set as the initial value...